# Teamcity perform GIT Checkout

Tags: git, build, teamcity

Team city agent which is currently performing the build does not have 'git' installed its a linux box. I cannot have git installed there.

Is there a native method in teamcity which can support the below in build step :

```
git checkout -b %dynamicversion%
```

Comment: TeamCity does support git. Documentation [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Git) and [here](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Git) might be helpful.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Creating a new branch on the agent based on parameter in teamcity? There is no native way to this on the agent AFAIK. BTW there are ways to get around no git, maybe you could use JGit on the agent. (TeamCity server uses it I think) Or maybe create an agent-side plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the VCS Root settings, you can set the Branch Specification.
The Branch Specification will allow you to run a specific branch (ie: `+:feature/*`)

Then a combo box will appear on the top of your project, in order to select your project.

If the branch to build depends of something in your code, you can do multiple configurations, with dependencies, and triggering using API.

**Build 1**

Build on `<default>` where you get the branch to run.
API Call on teamcity which will call Build 2 with the parameter `branch` set to the specified value:

```
# RunSpecificBranch.ps1
# PowerShell: Run Build Configuration on a specific branch
Param(
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$branchName,
     [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$BuildToRun
)
Begin
{
    $TCUrl = "http://&lt;teamcityURL&gt;/httpAuth/app/rest/buildQueue"
    Execute-HTTPPostCommand $TCUrl "<build branchName=""$branchName""><buildType id=""$buildToRun""/></build>"
}
```

And Execute this script like: `RunSpecificBranch.ps1 -branchName: feature/ME/AwesomeFeature -buildToRun: Project_SubProject_SpecificBuildOnBranch` inside your build Step.

The checkout of the branch will be done by the server before running the build configuration `Project_SubProject_SpecificBuildOnBranch`

**Build 2**

Specified to run on multiple branches as specified bellow, you will do here your custom logic that you need.

Comment: thanks, but the requirement is to strip a version from pom file and perform git checkout as a build step from the currently executing build.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question. You need to make sure git package is installed in the linux box, in order to do that you can do following things.

> I guess your using tracks in your Team city agent to run the linux.

If you use makefile or script, you can add a target which is call prepare-dev or "anymeaningfull_name" in that you can try to install the git package as prerequisites.

```
git checkout -b %dynamicversion%
```

What I understood, you want to checkout the latest branch which has buildversion tag.

> You can create ts.native.ini file add the dependecy package,
>
> ```
> suite: precise
> mirror: http://xx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
> components: main restricted universe
> packages: mtools devscripts gcc make git libgnutls28-dev libboost-test-dev sudo e2fsprogs
> prepare: make prepare-dev
> preparefiles: Makefile
> ```

Once after doing this you can add target. You can use it in your script.

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then
    echo "Please run as root"
    exit 1
fi
git clean -xfd
trap "$TRACKS -u" EXIT

_mkdebs()
{
    export TRACKS_INIFILE=ts.trusty(native).ini 
    $TRACKS -b -- make mkdebs CCACHE_DIR=$CCACHE_DIR
}
```

You can add ts.native.ini track file in your teamcity agent so that it will install all the prerequsities which is needed.